# Webview inside Flipview not working properly

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, msdn

i am trying to get Webview inside Flipview, so as usual it will be something like this :

```
<flipview>
    <flipview.itemtemplate>
         <datatemplate><webview name="wv" /> </datatemplate>
    </flipview.itemtemplate>
</flipview>
```

I would like to use wv.navigatetostring(htmlstring);

The problem now is, when i navigate through items, sometime the webview is updated, sometime its not. Any Suggestion?

Comment: Need more information. What do you mean by "sometimes updated"?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it is possible to use WebView inside FlipView, but **you should be aware of several limitations of this component**. There is a well known issue when using the WebView - **it's rendered on top of everything** so the swiping using touch between FlipView items might not be possible.

Nice article every developer should know before using WebView in Windows 8 application:
[Ten Things You Need to Know About WebView](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx)

Comment: In Windows 8.1 the rendering on top issue no longer applies: http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/appbuilder/archive/2013/07/17/what-s-new-in-webview-in-windows-8-1.aspx